# SystemD memcached service - (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Tags: systemd, service, memcached, rocky-linux

So I had to deploy in Rocky Linux 8 memcached with SOCKET in /var/run/memcached

In order to avoid the service to fail, I have run the following:

- systemctl edit memcached.service

Pasted in:

```
[Unit]
Description=Memcached
Before=httpd.service
After=network.target
[Service]
Type=simple
User=memcached
Group=memcached
# Run ExecStartPre with root-permissions
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/mkdir /var/run/memcached
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/chown -R memcached:memcached /var/run/memcached/
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

---

```
[root@cp monit.d]# service memcached status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status memcached.service
● memcached.service - Memcached
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/memcached.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/memcached.service.d
           └─override.conf
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2022-10-13 15:23:50 CEST; 3s ago
  Process: 1336192 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown -R memcached:memcached /var/run/memcached/ (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1336188 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir /var/run/memcached (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1336194 (memcached)
    Tasks: 10 (limit: 101049)
   Memory: 3.6M
   CGroup: /system.slice/memcached.service
           └─1336194 /usr/bin/memcached -p 11211 -u memcached -m 256 -c 1024 -s /var/run/memcached/memcached.sock -a 0770

Oct 13 15:23:50 cp.uhlhosting.ch systemd[1]: Starting Memcached...
Oct 13 15:23:50 cp.uhlhosting.ch systemd[1]: Started Memcached.
```

What would be a way to avoid this FAILURE?

```
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir /var/run/memcached (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing right now -- creating `/var/run/memcached` via `ExecStartPre` -- is fine, but the canonical way of handling this is via the [`systemd-tmpfiles`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service.html) service. You create `/etc/tmpfiles.d/memcache.conf` with the content:

```
D /run/memcached 0700 memcached memcached
```

This will create the directory `/run/memcached` (typically, `/var/run` is just a symlink to `/run`) whenever the system boots. This means you don't need to handle creating the directory in your service unit.

See also the [`tmpfiles.d` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/tmpfiles.d.5.html) and existing configuration files in either `/etc/tmpfiles.d` or in `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d`.